# How to show updated input box value in multiple places on an HTML page in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="order_date" id="order_date"/>
```

Upon updating the field, I want to display the value of that field in regular text in two other places on the same HTML page, in real time, as the field date is updated.  How?

JS tried:

```
<p>The date selected was <span id="place_one"></span></p>
<p>And using the date of <span id="place_two"></span></p>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#order_date").change(function(){
        $('#place_one').text($("#order_date").val());
        $('#place_two').text($("#order_date").val());
    });
})
```

Comment: Seems fairly basic. Please show us the JS you tried.

Comment: j08691, updated question

Comment: Much better, thanks. And the code you posted seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dyap4k0e/ so have you checked the console for errors? Did you load jQuery?

Comment: I think it was not working because I was using `val` and not `text`

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: I updated my question again to JS I have tried

Comment: Hmmm, why change the code you posted if it was working to something that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let orderDate = document.getElementById('order_date');
orderDate.addEventListener ("change", function () {
  let showHeres = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('show_here'));
  let value = this.value;
  showHeres.forEach(function(showHere) {
     showHere.innerText = value;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="date" name="order_date" id="order_date"/>

<p>The date selected was <span class="show_here"></span></p>
<p>And using the date of <span class="show_here"></span></p>
```

**EDIT:**
Your solutioin is also working:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#order_date").change(function(){
        $('#place_one').text($("#order_date").val());
        $('#place_two').text($("#order_date").val());
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="order_date" id="order_date"/>

<p>The date selected was <span id="place_one"></span></p>
<p>And using the date of <span id="place_two"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to format the value rather than display it as a unix date you can format it to a given locale.

EG:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#order_date").on("input",function(){
    var $input = $(this),
    val = $input.val(),
    date = new Date(val),
    longformat = {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'};
    $(".live_order_date").each(function(){
      var locale = $(this).data("locale") || "en-GB",
      verbose = $(this).data("verbose"),
      opts = (verbose)?longformat:{};
      $(this).text(date.toLocaleDateString(locale,opts));
    })
  });
});
```

```css
span {color:#666699;
font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="order_date" id="order_date"/>
<p>The date selected was <span class="live_order_date" data-locale="en-GB" data-verbose="true">...</span></p>
<p>And using the date of <span class="live_order_date" data-locale="en-GB">...</span><br/>
(or <span class="live_order_date" data-locale="en-US">...</span> if you're in the US)</p>
<p>What's that? you need it in Hindi <span class="live_order_date" data-locale="hi-IN" data-verbose="true">...</span>
```